# Phpmyadmin 500 Internal Server Error on debian 8

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I tried to install and configure my phpmyadmin but i have this error when i tried to acces on website/phpmyadmin

```
Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

this is what i have in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

```
[Wed Jun 17 06:25:03.213504 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 18553] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jun 17 06:25:03.213527 2020] [core:notice] [pid 18553] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Jun 17 17:06:21.488126 2020] [authn_file:error] [pid 22625] (2)No such file or directory: [client 88.125.106.51:64647] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd
```

I modified htaccess file with this

```
sudo nano /usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htaccess
```

and enter this content

```
AuthType Basic
Authname "Restricted files"
AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Comment: You need to look into your http server's error log file. That is where details about the issue are logged. Typically something like `/var/log/apache2/error.log` or similar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if you have created directives to tell Apache to restrict access based on user accounts that are defined in the `/etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd` file. Those are the four lines you added to the `.htaccess` file; you're telling Apache to use HTTP Basic authentication and to require a valid user contained in that file.

However, the message in `error.log` states that file doesn't exit or can't be read. You should either change your configuration in `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htaccess` (to point to the correct file), create the file `/etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd`, or check the permissions of `/etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd/` if it already exists so that Apache has permissions to read the file.

If the file does exist, Apache can't read it. Check the permissions and make sure that the Apache process has read permissions. If the file doesn't exist, you can create it: `htpasswd -c /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd any-username`. .htaccess users operate independently of operating system users.

You'll also benefit from becoming familiar with the Apache documentation: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/PasswordBasicAuth

Comment: where do I tell apache to use :  http basic authentification ? i don't really understand what u wanted to say with this ...
so i have the file of what you mantion and
my htaccess seem to point the good file
and i try this for the permission
`sudo chmod -R 755 etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd.setup`
`sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htaccess`
But i have the same error

Comment: "where do I tell apache to use : http basic authentification" Those are the four lines you added to the .htaccess file. The four directives that you've placed there are all parts of telling Apache to require a valid login before allowing access to the phpMyAdmin pages. In this case, a valid login is defined as the username and account appearing in `/etc/phpmyadmin/.htaccess`.

Comment: "sudo chmod -R 755 etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd.setup sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htaccess But i have the same error" Neither of these files are the file you have defined for authentication: `/etc/phpmyadmin/.htaccess`. I'm not sure about the file `htpasswd.setup`, I don't think that's created by the package manager either, but if you've created that manually then you need to either rename it to match the name defined in .htaccess or change the directive in .htaccess to match that name. Right now, it seems you have a file but are telling Apache to look for a different file name.